# How to add a new resource type to Rails scaffolding generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5

I know that it's possible to change individual generators in a Rails scaffold. For example, I can change test generator to RSpec:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
```

But how do I add *additional* type of generated resource?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I haven't :(

Comment: Looking at the source and from other answers, it does not look like it's possible. If I ever figure it out though, I'll post it here! :)